# Python class variable not updated by callback method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, callback

I am struggling with a class variable that does not 
get updated properly.

What I do is instantiate a class object and call one of its methods. this method will start a Process for async result handling. The process is given a callback method, which is an instance method from my object.
When my process is finished, a class variable should have been updated by the callback method. This didn't happen. During callback executing, everything looks fine.

Can someone point me at what I am doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
import logging
try:
    from multiprocessing import Process
except ImportError:
    # For pre 2.6 releases
    from threading import Thread as Process


def runner(printout, callback):
    command = "ls"
    data = subprocess.Popen(
        command,
        bufsize=100000,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    # wait until finished
    # get output
    (last_output, myerr) = data.communicate()
    last_output = bytes.decode(last_output)
    myerr = bytes.decode(myerr)
    if len(myerr) > 0:
        logging.debug(myerr)

    if printout and callable(callback):
        callback(last_output)
    return


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, myres):
        if myres is None:
            logging.warning("No result object given. Results will be printed to stdout only!")
        self.results = myres

    def _result_callback(self, scan_results):
        if scan_results:
            for line in scan_results.splitlines():
                self.results = self.results + line
                print(self.results)

    def task_starter(self):
        process = Process(
            target=runner,
            args=(True, self._result_callback),
        )
        process.daemon = True
        process.start()
        while process.is_alive():
            logging.debug("Still running...")
            process.join(2)


result = ""
myjob = MyClass(result)
myjob.task_starter()
print("\n")
print("SAME RESULT: %s" % myjob.results)
```

Thanks in advance,
ChocoRolls